# invalid literal for int() with base 10 Python

Tags: python, int, radix

Got an error above with the following code:

```
import optparse
import socket
from socket import *
from threading import *


def main():
    parser =optparse.OptionParser('usage%prog -H <target host> -p <target port>')
    parser.add_option('-p',dest='tgtPort',type='string',help='specific target port separated by comma')
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()

    tgtPorts = str(options.tgtPort).split(', ')
    for p in tgtPorts:
        print int(p)


if  __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

when I try to implement:

```
python testInt.py -p 20, 80
```

Expected result:

```
20 80
```

Comment: Just saying `separated by comma` in the help text for your argument doesn't make `argparse` actually treat comma-separated arguments the way you want. Heck, even before the arguments reach `argparse`, the shell's command line splitting isn't working the way you want. `tgtPort` is `"20,"`, and `"80"` ends up as an element of `args`.

Comment: (Oh, optparse, not argparse. Neither optparse nor the shell's command line splitting are going to do what you want here, though.)

Comment: `argparse` offers a few tools that could help, particularly if you don't want to quote your arguments, but comma-separated argument handling is going to be awkward. Shells are designed around space separation.

Comment: @user2357112 thanks so much for your solid explanation. Now I understand better about this.

Comment: @user2357112 I'm doing a tool, I learnt it from a book which does the same thing but it works, lmao. I was wondering why it doesn't work for me and try to catch it. Okay, thanks anyway/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm, when you call

```
python testInt.py -p 20, 80
```

`20,` is passed to the `-p` argument and `80` is included in the rest of the arguments.

You need to enclose them in quotes for it to work

```
python testInt.py -p "20, 80"
```

Comment: @Enderphan: Someone tells you you need to use a thing, and your first question is immediately how to get rid of the thing they said you need to use?

Comment: @user2357112 I want to know more Sir. I really appreciate if you can help.

Comment: @Enderphan , it is handled by the shell you are using. Essentially your shell will split a string (e.g a command) on whitespaces to create tokens which it will later try to interpret, except in specific cases like when using double quotes. In that case it will consider whatever inside quotes as one token and remove the quotes.